# ST_MakeValid() leaving data unaltered?

Tags: postgis, validation, postgis-2.3

I recently received a PostGIS instance and am trying to figure out how much of my current processing workflow (in proprietary tools) can be ported over to PostGIS.

One of the most frequent tasks I encounter is validating/repairing geometry.

Here's what I've done and here's where I'm stuck:

I load some data (multipolygon) to postGIS.  Then I use the following statement to identify and copy invalid geometries to a different table:

```
create table broken_polygons as
select * from polygons
where not st_isvalid(geom);
```

Then, I get rid of the offending records:

```
delete from polygons
where not st_isvalid(geom);
```

This gives me a chance to take a closer look at the bad geometry; sometimes there are only one or two, sometimes there are hundreds.  But when I try to do this:

```
select *, st_makevalid(geom) as fixed_polygons
from "broken_polygons"
```

It gives me a result, but when I load up `fixed_polygons` in QGIS and check the geometry validity (GEOS), all of them error out: nothing has been modified.

In this particular case, all of the errors are self-intersections.

I am using PostGIS 2.3.2 on postgres 9.6.2

I am not a DBA, just someone trying to get things done with the tools in front of me; so I seek examples of precise syntax to get ST_MakeValid to work.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect QGIS is picking the first geometry column it finds and since you are using *, the first geometry column would be the unchanged geom one.

Try instead to explicitly specify your columns.

```
SELECT gid, some_field, ST_MakeValid(geom) As fixed_geom
FROM broken_polygons;
```

In order to get the field to load correctly in QGIS, you may need to specify the geometry type (`LineString`, `Polygon`, etc.) for the new field. For polygonal data, you can do this as follows:

```
SELECT
  fid,
  name,
  ST_CollectionExtract(
    ST_Multi(
      ST_MakeValid(geom)
    ), 3)::geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326) AS fixed_geom
FROM broken_polygons
```

Comment: this generates a new table in postgis, but it just has a question-mark next to it, instead of being a geographic layer I can drag into QGIS.

Comment: Add a new row for the new table into geometry_columns.

Comment: try `ST_Multi(ST_MakeValid(geom))::geometry(MultiPolygon, your_srid_here)`. I think the issue is the generic `geometry` type returned by `ST_MakeValid`.

Comment: @dbaston so if I am using EPSG 4326, it would be `ST_Multi(ST_MakeValid(geom))::geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326)`?

Comment: So unfortunately I cannot get any parsing of this suggestion to work.  The suggestion does not demonstrate how to apply this specifically to my `broken_polygons` layer - I tried `SELECT fid, name, ST_Multi(ST_MakeValid(geom))::geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326) FROM broken_polygons;` and it said that the geometry collection doesn't match (even though `broken_polygons` is a MultiPolygon type).

Comment: @auslander In that case it may be that `ST_MakeValid` is generating geometries that have non-polygonal components (for example, converting a degenerate polygon into a line). You can add `ST_CollectionExtract` to the mix to pull out only the polygons.

Comment: @dbaston if I could impose on a few more seconds of your time to ask *how* to "add it to the mix" I would greatly appreciate it.  Again, not a DBA here, and I'm slowly learning PostGIS, but for now I'm just looking for a way to do this quickly (as opposed to just firing up ArcGIS again and running "Repair Geometry")

Comment: sorry, I mean to add it to the chain of function calls, like `SELECT fid, name, ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Multi(ST_MakeValid(geom)), 3)::geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326) AS geom FROM broken_polygons`

Comment: @dbaston, awesome, that worked.  Using QGIS's GEOS method for checking validity, the dataset now returns valid output.  should this be made its own answer to be marked correct?